# Module background for Joomla

Tags: joomla, background, module

I want to add background to language switch bar and login bar as shown on the image below:
http://s21.postimg.org/ra5z6djyv/Untitled_1.jpg

I have two modules called "position2" and "position1" for these two sections.

I can also associate "Custom class" of the module with specific code in my template.css so I need just a code for the style. What CSS should I put to my template to make this work?

Here are my codes and by adding them Im getting this:
http://s30.postimg.org/6yjew3601/Untitled_1.jpg

CODE FOR "postion1":

```
.flag-container {
    background:#88e1f9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
border: 0px solid #800000;
}
```

CODE FOR "position2":

```
.box-color {
    background:#88e1f9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px; 
border: 0px solid #800000;
}
```

/*additional code for buttons style*/

```
.box-color ul
{
float:center;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
}
.box-color a
{
float:right;
text-align:center;
width:4em;
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
background-color:transparent;
padding:0.2em 0.6em;
border-width:1px solid black;
}
.box-color a:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
.box-color li {display:inline;}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I assume by what you've written, you know about [Module Class Suffix's](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix). Once you have done this, let's say you add the class "**custom**", your CSS will simply be like this:

```
.custom {
    background: #62BBDD;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

which you can add to your *template.css* file.

You can change `#62BBDD` to whatever colour you wish

**Update:**
Without looking at your site, it's very hard to figure out how to remove the spacing so the only thing I'm going to suggest is a "quick fix" solution.

add this to your `.flag-container` class CSS:

```
position: relative;
right: 40px;
```

So it will finally look like this:

```
.flag-container {
    background:#88e1f9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px; 
    border: 0px solid #800000;
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
```

Note that you will probably need to change `40px` until it meets the other container

Comment: How I can round the corners on two bottom sides? Should I make some.jpg or could it be done with pure CSS? If I add "custom" class to modules "position2 and position1" it will make square background to both of them.  
Thank you!

Comment: @mrwad - I have updated my answer. Simply with pure CSS. If this has answred your question, please accept the answer by clicking the "tick" icon to the left of it

Comment: Hey, I have ended up with this: http://s30.postimg.org/6yjew3601/Untitled_1.jpg 
by adding CSS provided. How I can fill the space between them and make upper padding 0 and also shrink the lenght of each a little bit?

Comment: I don't know as I don't have a link to your site and therefore can't inspect the element with Firebug. Please do try something of your own and don't expect all your work to be done for you.

Comment: I am trying to do my best and expected someone with more knowlage to share it with me maybe someone else in the same situation as well. I have added code I used to get the result. Site is currently on my localhost so I don't have the link for it.
Thank you for effort!